# Having MainViewController, how to communicate with actual UIContainerViews within MainVC?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have `MainViewController` that has 4 `UIContainerViews`.

I have different `UIBarButtonItem` on the `MainViewController` depending which `ContainerView` is shown.

When I click `UIBarButtonItem`, I want to communicate with the `UIViewController` of the specific `UIContainerView`.

How to approach that?

I have tried having a `static func` on the child VC and did not work. Also, `self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier` but eventually, it is instantiating, not getting the displayed VC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set identifier for each container segue in interfaceBuilder.
- Define a placeholder for each container in the MainViewController class:

````
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    var container1: UIViewController!
    var container2: UIViewController!
    var container3: UIViewController!
    var container4: UIViewController!

    ```
}
````

- Assign each placeholders with the actual value inside `prepare(for segue...` function:

````
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    ```

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let identifier = segue.identifier else { return }
        switch identifier {
        case "Segue1": container1 = segue.destination
        case "Segue2": container2 = segue.destination
        case "Segue3": container3 = segue.destination
        case "Segue4": container4 = segue.destination
        default: return
        }
    }
}
````

now you have access to each view controller separately.

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you very much.